# ElasticSearch with Spark - error at runtime

Tags: scala, elasticsearch, apache-spark, spark-streaming

Getting an error when running the ElasticSearch Spark example code, that i took mostly from the [start page][1].
The error is:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   scala.Predef$.ArrowAssoc(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;    at
>   org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.EsSpark$.saveToEs(EsSpark.scala:52)

Here is my sbt config:

```
scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

resolvers += "Typesafe Repo" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"
resolvers += "Conjars" at "http://conjars.org/repo"

resolvers += "cljars" at "https://clojars.org/repo/"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.5.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming_2.10" % "1.5.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.elasticsearch" % "elasticsearch" % "1.7.2"
libraryDependencies +="org.elasticsearch" % "elasticsearch-hadoop" % "2.1.1"
```

Here is the code that fails: (last line)

```
      val upcomingTrip = Trip("OTP", "SFO")
   val lastWeekTrip = Trip("MUC", "OTP")
   val rdd = sc.makeRDD(Seq(upcomingTrip, lastWeekTrip))             
   EsSpark.saveToEs(rdd, "spark/docs")
```

Run with:

```
bin/spark-submit --jars $(echo ../../elasticsearch-hadoop-2.1.1/dist/elasticsearch-spark-1.2_2.11-2.1.1.jar  | tr ' ' ',')  --class "Test"  --master local[4]   target/scala-2.10/simple-project_2.10-1.0.jar localhost 9999
```

I tried changing the scala version to 2.11.4, and ran into problem when compiling.
Any idea?

Comment: Have you made the proper imports?

Comment: `NoSuchMethodError` usually happens when the method was available at compile time (i.e. the method could be properly resolved when the code was compiled and linked) but isn't available anymore at runtime because 1) the corresponding library is not available or 2) the library version is different on the deployment host.

Comment: What happens when you do `import org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.EsSpark`?

Comment: I got same error on spark 2.0-preview and es 2.3.3, can anybody tell me if it is possible to use spark 2.0-preview with RDDs to save to ES